# How do you recursively select all child elements under a parent element?

Tags: t-sql

Let's say we've got this table:

```
WORKER  
NAME     ID    ManagerID  
------------------------
John     1     3  
Sally    2     3  
Paul     3     4  
Jane     4     5  
Jennifer 5     8
```

So John and Sally work for Paul, and Paul works for Jane.

For the SQL query, I want to feed it Jane's ID (4) and have it return back all of her subordinates:

```
John     1     3  
Sally    2     3  
Paul     3     4
```

I would also need for this query to recursively go as deep as is needed.  For example, maybe John has people working for him, so they would be included in the results too.

---

How would you build this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([NAME] varchar(50),[ID] varchar(50),[ManagerID] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 ('John',1,3)
,('Sally',2,3)
,('Paul',3,4)
,('Jane',4,5)
,('Jennifer',5,8)
,('Boss',8,null) 


Declare @Top    int         = 4      --<<  NULL for Full Hier
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ManagerId 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ManagerId ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ManagerId 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ManagerId  = p.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,A.ManagerId 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
 From  cteP A
 Order By Seq
```

Returns

```
ID  ManagerId   Lvl Name
4   5           1   Jane
3   4           2   |-----Paul
1   3           3   |-----|-----John
2   3           3   |-----|-----Sally
```

Answer (score 1):

This page shows how to put it together using TSQL:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple recursive cte for this as below:

```
;With cte as (
    Select * from YourWorker where ManagerId = 4

    union all

    select y.WorkerName, y.Id, y.ManagerId from YourWorker y inner join cte c
    on y.ManagerId = c.Id
)
select * from cte
```

Output as below:

```
+------------+----+-----------+
| WorkerName | Id | ManagerId |
+------------+----+-----------+
| Paul       |  3 |         4 |
| John       |  1 |         3 |
| Sally      |  2 |         3 |
+------------+----+-----------+
```